# R Shiny - Run application in background and issue UI controls with code

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a vignette for my Shiny application package. At the beginning of my vignette, I source a file called `screenshots.R` that produces nice screenshots of my application. I am producing them like so:

```
webshot::appshot(mypackage::run_datepicker_app(),
                 file = "man/figures/datepicker.png", vwidth = 500, vheight = 200)
```

This works great and it gives me a great screenshot of what is - in this case - a couple `dateInput` fields. However, I'd like to be able to get a screenshot of the `dateInput` in use (say, with the calendar selection exposed).

Is there a way to issue commands to the application object in a script so I can get screenshots of the application in use, rather than having to do it manually?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `ShinyDriver` from the `shinytest` package?

You can use `shinytest` to have a headless browser run the app, interact with it, and take screenshots programmatically. If you don't have phantomJS installed, you'll need to run `shinytest::installDependencies()` before using `ShinyDriver`. All you need to do is point it to a directory containing a shiny app (in my case, the folder is 'myApp').

```
install.packages("shinytest")
shinytest::installDependencies()

app <- shinytest::ShinyDriver$new("myApp")
app$takeScreenshot("screenshot1.png")
button <- app$findElement("#button")
button$click()
Sys.sleep(1)
app$takeScreenshot("screenshot2.png")                
app$stop()
```

I am starting the app in a headless browser, taking a screenshot, finding the button with the id 'button', clicking it, and taking another screenshot, then closing the app. Navigate to specific elements using "#id", where id is just the id you gave the shiny input. You can specify a file path to a png file in the `takeScreenshot` calls, so that you can then use them in your code elsewhere. Note that you may need to use `Sys.sleep` to stop the screenshots from being taken before the UI updates.